# Using Node.js to track XMLHTTPRequests

Tags: javascript, node.js, streaming, xmlhttprequest

I've just started learning Node.js and was very interested in its real-time capabilities, especially with Socket.io. Since then, I've written a very basic script to connect to Twitter's streaming server and broadcast tweets to all connected clients.

To build that, I used `http.createClient` to connect to stream.twitter.com and added in the relevant `response` and `data` event handlers. Everything works quite well.

Obviously, Twitter's Streaming API pretty much outputs an infinitely loading webpage and what why using a `data` event handler works fairly well with it. However, is it possible to make other types of websites 'streamable'?

For example, if a client (browser) updates a website periodically using an XMLHTTPRequest, would it be possible to track the output of those requests using the HTTP API of Node.js? Or similar Node.js extension?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

websites do not periodically use XMLHTTPRequest. Clients periodically send XMLHTTPRequests to an URL.

A simple call to `http.request(options, callback)` with the correct headers should emulate XHR's. Most of these servers will also accept normal POST or GET requests.

If you want node.js to connect to a server and simulate a browser then something like [zombie](http://zombie.labnotes.org/) would serve you well. It claims to support XMLHTTPRequest.

Comment: Hi, you're right. I phrased the last example incorrectly and have updated the question to reflect it. What I was getting at was, since I'm creating a client using, for example, `var c = http.createClient(port, host)`, is there anyway for that `http` client, `c` to simulate a regular client/browser and execute any javascript within it (including calling all XMLHTTPRequests associated with it)?

Comment: @KishyrRamdial do you want node.js to connect to the server. Or do you want node.js to be a middle man?

Comment: Essentially what I want to do is have node.js connect to one of our web dashboards (that updates itself using XMLHttpRequests), be notified that the dashboard has been updated, and perform an action (send an email, etc).

Comment: @KishyrRamdial Try looking at zombie.js.

Answer (score 0):

The best case for you would be to use web-sockets between your dashboard and node server. This way node will be notified immediately that something has updated at your dashboard ( I am assuming that you can modify your dashboard a bit to accept such connections, won't be difficult as long as you have access).

Then you can use long polling at client-end i.e. send a request to the node server and wait. Node will receive the request and then register an event to it. The moment it receives the updates from dashboard, it'll fire the event which will send the response to all the clients one by one waiting.

I would recommend take a look at http://github.com/andrewdavey/vogue . It does something similar but the functionality is ofcourse different.

Comment: That requires chaning the dashboard code. What if he doesn't have access to the clientside code or can't change it?

Comment: I assumed he might as he mentioned it as 'our dashboards'. If he doesn't then I don't think there is anything you could do other than have a chain of polling requests. One from client to node (long polling) and second from node to dashboard (on intervals). The thing is that IF he has the access then HE should go with sockets. It's the most efficient solution even if it requires tweaking a large/legacy/working server.

Comment: @nEEBz depends whether it's worthwhile editing a large existing code base to make addding this new functionality easier.

Comment: @raynos: You think if with some tweaks we can have web sockets rather that polling at regular intervals, it's not worth it?

Comment: @nEEbz "with some tweaks" what you actually mean is a major rewrite.

Comment: Raynos is right. I'm looking at existing production sites and won't be able to make changes to their codebases. Was looking at a solution that doesn't require making any changes to the websites. Zombie seems do what I need it to do.